# Custom key combinations in dwm

Tags: key-mapping, dwm

I have some custom key combinations in `config.h`, which work great.

I just got a 60% keyboard, and would like to configure the arrow keys to work Vim-like ¨hjkl¨, instead of the combination with <kbd>FN</kbd> + arrows.

I tried to use `xmodmap` but if I define Muhenkan key as a Mode key, it will interfere with the usual behaviour of dwm (<kbd>Mod</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> for previous window).

Is there any way I can define:

```
keycode 102 (Muhenkan) + keycode 44 (j) = Down
```

Comment: Can you identify a [keysym for that pairing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_keyboard_keys_in_Xorg#Window_managers)?

Comment: tried `xbindkeys` but feel a bit confuse on how to define a "key Down action" in the code `"Down" m:0x10 + c:44 Mod2 + j` which is actually not working.

Comment: If you have a keysym, you just write a keys rule in `config.h`...

Comment: I know how to create shortcuts to call an application, but I am afraid I could't find a single example on how to combine two keys to create a third key simulation.

Comment: What is the keysym for your desired combination?

Comment: `m:0x10 + c:44` shoud give `0xFF54`. In other words: `keycode 102 (Muhenkan) + keycode 44 (j) = Down`